# Minimum number of line segments to cover a bigger line

Tags: java, algorithm, greedy

I am given the coordinates of **n** line segments (1-dimensional) of same length, and I need to find the minimal number of these line segments to fully cover the bigger line or find out that this is impossible.

The bigger line starts from **0** and ends at **L**. The line segments can start from the range **[0-D, L-D]** and all have the same length **2*D**.

So, for example for the following input:

```
15 2 4 // L, n, D
-2 7  // beginning coordinates of line segments

21 14 4
10 4 6 3 16 17 -1 2 14 11 12 8 5 1

9 9 3
-2 -1 4 0 5 -3 6 3 1

14 12 5
-3 -2 7 5 3 -4 2 -5 0 8 9 6
```

There's the following output:

```
Case #1: impossible
Case #2: 3
Case #3: 2
Case #4: 2
```

In order to solve this problem I use the greedy algorithm and choose line segments, so that the intersections between them are minimal. Here's my java code:

```
// read L, n, D
// read line segments to segments[] array
segments[n] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
Arrays.sort(segments);
int current = -1;
for (int i = n-1; i >= 0; i--)
    if (segments[i] <= 0) {
        current = i;
        break;
    }
if (current == -1) {
    System.out.println("Case #" + k + ": impossible");
    continue;
}
int count = 1;
boolean poss = true;
for (int i = 0; i < L - 2* D;) {
    count++;
    int next = getNextSegment(current);
    if (next == current) {
        poss = false;
        break;
    }
    current = next;
    i = segments[current];
}
if (!poss)
    System.out.println("Case #" + k + ": impossible");
else
    System.out.println("Case #" + k + ": " + count);
```

And here is my helper method that gets the next line segment:

```
int getNextSegment(int current) {
    int i = current;
    while (segments[i] <= segments[current] + 2* D)
        i++;
    return i-1;
}
```

My algorithms produces the aforementioned output correctly, but there's still some bug in my code and I wasn't be able to find the test case, where my program fails. What do you think should be fixed?

Comment: Can you describe the bug a bit more?  "Some bug in my code" is too vague.

Comment: If you have done competitive programming, you will get these cases, where you just know that your code is wrong as system doesn't accept your solution, but you don't know exactly what is the problem. Because on the provided test cases your program works perfectly fine.

Comment: I don't think this is a problem for which a greedy algo is guaranteed to give the correct answer.

Comment: Can you link to the original problem?

Comment: Are you getting WA or TLE?

Comment: I'm getting wrong answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to edit your solution to generate the correct output for all data sets listed on the provided link. My edits are as follows:

- Changed `segments` array from size `n+1` to size `n`, removing the Integer.MAX_VALUE entry at the end.
- Changed `segments[i] <= 0` to `segments[i]-D <= 0` for cases where there is no entry <= 0, but there is an entry that intersects 0.
- Changed the for loop header from `for (int i = 0; i < L - 2 * D;)` to `for (int i = 0; i < L - D;)`
- Added a boundary check in the `getNextSegment` method.

For reference, my resulting code is as follows:

```
Arrays.sort(segments);
int current = -1;
for (int i = n-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (segments[i]-D <= 0) {
        current = i;
        break;
    }
}
if (current == -1) {
   System.out.println("Case #" + k + ": impossible");
   continue;
}
int count = 1;
boolean poss = true;
for (int i = segments[current]; i < L-D;) {
    count++;
    int next = getNextSegment(current);
    if (next == current) {
        poss = false;
        break;
    }
    current = next;
    i = segments[current];
}
if (!poss)
    System.out.println("Case #" + k + ": impossible");
else
    System.out.println("Case #" + k + ": " + count);
```

With the edited `getNextSegment` method looking like this:

```
int getNextSegment(int current) {
    int i = current;
    while(i < segments.length && segments[i] <= segments[current] + 2 * D)
        i++;
    return i - 1;
}
```

Comment: Online judge accepted the solution. +1 and accept from me, thanks! You just had a small flaw in the solution, namely you were starting to iterate from 0, although sometimes firstly chosen segment is already > 0. Please see edit.